# Graded watching for Korean

Tags: resource-request, listening, korean

I'm sure most people here know of graded readers for language learning, but I'm wondering if there are any resources for "graded watching" in Korean. I'll be making a similar post to ask about Spanish, my other target language.

This is a resource that I saw someone mention somewhere online which lists shows and movies for advanced Chinese learners: http://www.jiong3.com/gradedwatching/.

If you know of any similar resources for Korean, I would love to hear about them, regardless of what language proficiency they're targeted towards! If the resources you know of "grade" shows/movies but in a very different way to the above site, that would be just as useful! Thank you!